# NUnit vs. xUnit

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, xunit

What are the differences between [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) and [xUnit.net](https://xunit.net/)?
What's the point of developing two of them, not only one?

I've read that xUnit is being developed by inventor of NUnit:

> xUnit.net is a unit testing tool for the .NET Framework. **Written by**
> the original **inventor of NUnit**

On the other hand:

> NUnit is a unit-testing framework for all .Net languages .. the
> current production release, version 2.6, is the seventh major release
> of this **xUnit based unit testing tool**

So where is the truth?

Comment: As @Joey has pointed out - this isn't a straight duplicate of the linked question. In this case, the OP has fundamentally misunderstood something; namely the difference between xUnit.net - the unit testing tool and *x*Unit - the generalised term for the class of unit testing frameworks (nUnit, jUnit, etc.). Voting to repopen.

Answer (score 220):

At the time of writing this answer, the latest NUnit version is v3.5 and xUnit.net is v2.1.

Both frameworks are awesome, and they both support parallel test running (in a different way though). **NUnit** has been around since 2002, it's widely used, well documented and has a large community, whereas **xUnit.net** is more modern, more TDD adherent, more extensible, and also trending in .NET Core development. It's also well documented.

In addition to that, the main difference I noticed is the way that xUnit.net runs the test methods. So, in **NUnit**, we've got a test class and a set of test methods in it.

**NUnit** creates a new instance of the test class and then runs all of the test methods from the same instance.

Whereas, **xUnit.net** creates a new instance of the test class for each of the test methods.

Therefore, one cannot use fields or properties to share data among test methods which is a bad practice, as our test methods would be dependent to each other which is not acceptable in TDD. So if you use xunit.net, you could be sure that your test methods are completely isolated.

If you're willing to share some data among your test methods though, xUnit will let you do so. Therefore, by default all test methods are completely isolated, but you can break this isolation in specific cases intentionally. I fancy this attitude, that's why I like it better.

Comment: What you write about parallel execution is not true. Maybe it was at the time of your post but now it is not. Check this https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel. It says that test methods in one class will never run parallelly.

Comment: Thanks @Gondil , you're right, it won't run methods of a single class in parallel. tweaked the parallelism bit

Comment: I am not sure how you found out that xUnit is "well documented", as it clearly doesn't. All information has to be found through community sources and stackoverflow questions instead of good documentation like NUnit does. I was truly excited about xUnit after your answer, but figured that NUnit seems to be doing fine in .NET Core as well.

Comment: So, based on Akazemis answer and wordpress post, I understand it's a matter of documentation/community (NUnit) vs better parallelism, isolation, a little more code readability and latest tech (XUnit). I will personally start trying XUnit first, and if I happen to have any trouble with it or find it too complicated, then I will change to NUnit. I Suggest the same thing for newbies to testing in c#, like myself.

Comment: @Loaderon I posted that around 4 years ago and I've been using xunit since then up until now. the documentation and the community is way better than before and it's more mature now. so use XUnit with peace of mind, you won't need to fallback to NUnit. :)

Comment: @akazemis How is [the documentation](https://xunit.net/#documentation) "better"? It *barely* exists at the moment. I dread to think what it was four years ago. I would definitely not call the documentation now "more mature" given that it would lend somebody to think it *has* maturity. Information about the library can only be found through various third part sources with unknown origin and quality. I found this post after searching for xUnit's documentation and...well, if that's what one gets out of such search I must say, I'm not going to express any support for "well documented".

Comment: As of NUnit 3.13, you can opt-in to use one instance per test method with the FixtureLifeCycle class annotation:

`[FixtureLifeCycle(LifeCycle.InstancePerTestCase)]`

https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/fixturelifecycle.html

Answer (score 47):

You're confusing the name of a single tool ([xUnit.net](https://github.com/xunit/xunit)) with the name of a whole class of unit testing frameworks ([xUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit), the *x* referring to a language/environment, e.g. JUnit, NUnit, ...).

Comment: Pity this got closed, since it isn't a straight duplicate - you are right - the OP has got confused between two terms that are almost the same.

Comment: I've slightly changed the title, to make sure that there will be no confusion.

Comment: I didn't go by the title but rather the highlighted segments of the quotes in your question. But maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: NUnit is the C# version of JUnit (Java). xUnit is an improvement of NUnit to make this more extensible for TDD. So is not the name of the tool, they are different tools.

Comment: This does not answer the question, really.

Answer (score 18):

While this was asked 10 years ago, the situation was really changed.

[Here's a good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLbF8u46tfE) comparing xUnit, NUnit and MSTest with code examples
Once you'll see it that here and there and there Nunit has something, while others don't or have less.

I will not say some tolerant things about xUnit (as well as about about MSTest) - a bad documented green sandbox with broken understanding of TDD, bad documentation and lack of cool features. Also, TDD is a concept, not a framework or smth to be limited by IDE or framework. If 'you' need borders to follow TDD and not to write a bad code, then you need to read books, not to design new framework or use xUnit.

what is xUnit?

- almost no documentation
- no setupt and teardown, manually written wrappers instead
- no onetimesetup (imagine you write integration or e2e tests and need to setup default DB data)
- no writeline
- no test context
- no other cool attributes which helps to control and decorate tests better
- poor assertions
- poor parallelism settings

MSTest is the only one concurrent for it. Does anyone in enterprise replace framework with MSTest?  I think no.

NUnit is a modern full power easy to use and to learn framework which is top 1 for 20+ years. It has full documentation, good architecture (xUnit doesn't have Setup and onetimesetup? Seriously replace it with constructor? It's like to name a bug as feature instead of fixing), good community and no childhood problems.

Answer (score 15):

xUnit Pros:

xUnit follows a new concept by avoiding the old "SetUp" and "TearDown" methods. It forces us to use IDisposable and a constructor as we should do as .NET developers. Also xUnit has a clear context sharing concept.

xUnit Cons:

Availability to get the test context is not implemented yet.

Comment: What is *"test context"*? Has it been implemented by now?

Comment: test context would give us information about current test (for example name of the test).
From what I am aware it is probably not implemented yet :(.

Answer (score 13):

One benefit of xUnit is that it finds tests in different classes and **runs them in parallel**. This can save a lot of time if you have many test cases.

You can of course turn this off, or control its operation (number of threads, threads per class, tests per assembly, etc).

Check out [this sample solution with two test projects, one using xUnit, the other NUnit](https://github.com/conradakunga/TestAnalysis).

You can read more about parallel tests in xUnit [here](https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel).

Comment: Does xunit have any other ways to make tests in the same class to run in parallel?

Answer (score 9):

As of 2023, I believe it doesn't matter much as to which of the two testing frameworks you choose, both offer somewhat similar features in different ways.

Different audience may choose a particular framework based on their needs, but for most general purpose, here are the few key things I would look for in a test framework

1. Writing clear and easy to read assertions
2. Easier lifecycle of test classes and no hidden surprises in terms of the behaviour.
3. My test framework is a piece of code that helps me test and maintain my codebase and I want it to be easy to use, have good community support and well documented.

Now comparing the xunit.net & nunit based on my preferences

1. Assertions - Both xunit.net & nunit have Assert classes which allows us to write assertions for different cases like checking equality, exception, inconclusive, skippable test cases etc. Both are at par with each other. People also use FluentAssertions library widely with these testing frameworks for easy to read assertions.
2. Console runner - Both xunit.net & nunit have command-line test runner. But to my surprise, xunit.net does not allow passing arguments from command-line directly. It suggests that we should ideally pass arguments from external sources like environment variables/configuration file. This opinionated argument doesn't really make a lot of sense to me.

   Nunit on the other hand, has built in support for passing arguments to test cases.
3. Test life cycle -  If you want to setup some connection variables/common setup variables at test instance level, both support it in different ways. I would say xunit.net started with a very opinionated mindset to not support setup and teardown methods. Their argument is that it makes the code difficult to read and debug.I don't really buy this argument. They recommend us to use constructor for setup and IDisposable interface for teardown operations. Nunit on the other hand, has SetUp and TearDown methods which can be used for setting up and disposing variables at instance level. Please be ensured that every test case will create new instance of the classes/variables you declare in SetUp method unless you declare static variables.

   Both also support setup & teardown at fixture level. Again, xunit.net complicates this with need for extending interfaces. Nunit has OneTimeSetup and OneTimeTearDown methods for the same.
4. Community support - I have personally explored both framework's documentations and prefer nunit's documentation better. xunit.net barely has documentation, I am welcome to objections here. Both have good community support on stackoverflow and help is available.
5. Parallelism - I personally don't think about performance / parallelism of test cases while choosing a test framework but xunit.net does offer good support for parallelism at fixture level, test instance level and assembly level. nunit also provides support for parallelism at test instance and class fixture level.

To conclude, both offer similar features. The opinions and the justifications for imposed by xunit.net doesn't really make a lot of sense to me. I would rather go with nunit for the simplicity of use that if offers.

Comment: You are right on Test life cycle. I find SetUp functions essential.

Answer (score 5):

There's one feature that makes me switching from XUnit (2.x) to NUnit (3.x), is that:

**XUnit doesn't work with `Console.WriteLine()`, while NUnit does.**

I can't describe how frustrated I am when I found that there's no easy way to get `Console.WriteLine` working in XUnit, especially when I'm trying get a short piece of code to work.

I think this is a standard benchmark user case that you should always make standard output work with your testing framework. I know it's not good practice, I know there're alternatives like output handler and stuff. Users trying out `Console.WriteLine` are especially new users, and failing to print anything to screen is very, very disappointing and frustrating.

Comment: I think `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.Error.WriteLine` alike are added in .NET 6 xUnit. Even before that, you could get `ITestOutputHelper` in the constructor.

Comment: you really need to consider using logger instead of console.WriteLine

Comment: this is not true anymore. Check .Net6 also check ITestOutputHelper which was there in past.

Comment: [It warns you if you pay attention.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVJHD.png)

Comment: @TimTIMWong it seems not.

Answer (score 3):

**1. xUnit has compact API. NUnit has much more methods, attributes and syntax for fluent assertions.**

```
Equal(2, a);                   // xUnit
Assert.That(a, Is.EqualTo(2)); // NUnit
```

**2. xUnit calls constructor of test-class for each test method. In contrast, NUnit calls constructor once for entire test class.**

Therefore, with NUnit you must setup your test in method, marked as [SetUp] attribute.

In [xUnit](https://xunit.net/) following tests will [pass](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context), because tests are isolated from each other:

```cs
int _a = 3;

[Fact]
public void Test1() => Equal(3, _a++);

[Fact]
public void Test2() => Equal(3, _a++);
```

In NUnit following tests will **fail**:

```cs
int _a = 3;

[Test]
public void Test1() => Assert.That(_a++, Is.EqualTo(3));

[Test]
public void Test2() => Assert.That(_a++, Is.EqualTo(3)); // NUnit fails here
```

**3. Difference in nuget structure**

Many developers wish to use the [xUnit](https://xunit.net/) or NUnit framework as a test runner, but with a different assertion library.

Acording to this [page](https://xunit.net/docs/nuget-packages), developers can replace xUnit asserts with, for example, FluentAssertions.

In contrasr, NUnit is tightly coupled with NUnit.Asserts. You can add assertion library, but not replace.

Answer (score 1):

I will add my experience, missed by others - in NUnit you are forced to initialize every field in *[SetUp]* method which has two implications

- sometimes you would prefer to have initialization along with declaration to  increase readability
- sometimes you may find yourself in tricky hard to debug situation in which tests are not deterministic because of one small initialization written (unnoticed) at declaration level

Despite it looks nice to have setup in additional method with explicit attribute saying what it's for, but it is not natural, we don't write our regular code this way thus I prefer regular object initialization.

I like for example initializations like this:

```cs
public class Tests
{
  private readonly DateTime _fakeCurrentTime = F.Create<DateTime>();
```

For me it's clear and easy to read. I prefer it much more than:

```cs
public class Tests
{
  private DateTime _fakeCurrentTime; # can't use readonly here which feels unnatural

  [SetUp]
  public void SetUp()
  {
    _fakeCurrentTime = F.Create<DateTime>();
  }
```

Such NUnit setup is not optional (for someone preferring this for readability), it's mandatory, and skipping it for just one field may cause tricky non-deterministic tests (which happened to me few times, despite understanding how NUnit works, working with it for years).

So in my view simpler, more natural and more clear is regular class initialization we do use in production code.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit and xUnit are both popular unit testing frameworks for .NET. Both frameworks provide similar functionality for creating and running unit tests, but there are some key differences between the two.

One of the main differences is the syntax used to write test cases. NUnit is based on the older JUnit framework for Java and follows a similar structure for organizing tests, including attributes for defining test fixtures, setup, and teardown methods.

For example, in NUnit, you would write a test case like this:

```
public class MyTests {
    [Test]    
    public void TestMethod() {
        // test code here
    }
}
```

In xUnit, you would write a test case like this:

```
public class MyTests {
    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod() {
        // test code here
    }
}
```

Another difference is that xUnit has built-in support for data-driven tests, which allows you to run the same test case with different input data. NUnit also supports data-driven tests, but it requires you to use a separate library or attribute.

xUnit also provides support for async testing, which allows you to write asynchronous test cases using the async and await keywords. NUnit also supports async testing, but it requires you to use a separate library or attribute.

Both frameworks are actively maintained and supported, so it largely comes down to personal preference. Some developers prefer the more concise and expressive syntax of xUnit, while others prefer the more traditional attribute-based syntax of NUnit.