# Trying to decide which framework to choose - Automation

Tags: c#, automation, nunit, mstest, xunit

So i trying to understand which framework will be the best for the long run hopefully that we won't need to change it to something else.

The background is that I want to build automation with selenium, appium, and wrap it up with gherkin for nice-looking tests =]

The tests should be able to choose 2 phone devices from device farm, and than after reading data from there to compare it to the data in the browser. (lets say I sent message and than I want to see if its also sent on the browser)

So the big question is

- Nunit
- Xunit
- MStest

Which one do you guys think will suit better for those needs I stated at the top?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you read the answer to this question here - [NUnit vs. xUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769047/nunit-vs-xunit).

You would be much interested in this part of that answer much better - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40220724/7790584